# cannot scroll to a web element as it is covered by other element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Java and Selenium to write a test. the target application has some inner pages, and I need to scroll to top of a web element in one the pages. I used:

```
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollTop", element);
```

but it did not work, I also used `scrollIntoView` but it did not work as the element is covered by another element.

Comment: You may want to add the mark-up for the page to your question.  As it stands now, there isn't enough information to provide an answer.

Comment: I used `scrollIntoView(false)` and it worked

Comment: The answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35355643/selenium-webdriver-element-not-clickable-error-in-firefox/35359067#35359067  should help you.

Answer (score 0):

**Update** Just saw your comment, glad you got it working in a more succinct way.

---

Make the element in the foreground invisible, then use scrollIntoView().

...Something like `jse.executeScript('arguments[0].style.visibility="hidden"', element)`?

My Python solution, it should translate easily:

```
def makeInvisible(driver, element):
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].style.visibility="hidden"', element)
```

I usually get the element by xpath and then pass it to that function. You can also double-check if something is hidden with an equivalent for:

```
def isInvisible(driver, element):
    return driver.execute_script('return window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0]).display === \'none\'', element)
```

And of course write a function to make an element visible again with the above.
Hope that helps!